# What is the Miller index of the highest site?

Tags: pymatgen, adsorption

I am trying to use [Pymatgen adsorption module](https://pymatgen.org/pymatgen.analysis.html#module-pymatgen.analysis.adsorption) for my adsorption site calculations. While going through the documentation, I had a small confusion. It says the following

1. Determine “surface sites” by finding those within a height threshold along the
   miller index of the highest site
2. Create a network of surface sites using the Delaunay triangulation
   of the surface sites
3. Assign on-top, bridge, and hollow adsorption sites at the nodes,
   edges, and face centers of the Del. Triangulation
4. Generate structures from a molecule positioned at these sites.

I didn't understand the first point. What does it mean by "Miller index of the highest sites"? Is it talking about some threshold value, or is it something else?
Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: +1 and welcome to our new community! Do you know what Miller indices are?

Comment: Yes, I know what Miller indices are.@NikeDattani

Comment: Then I wonder why you asked what "Miller index of the highest sites" means rather than what "highest sites" means?